# Python script that runs GET request loop throws "KeyError", but not every time

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, python-requests

I have created a python script that allows me to run through a loop in order to process several GET requests. I am then pulling the value for each request for a field called "creative" and then printing the final counts of both "True" and "False" values at the end of the script. Here is what my code looks like:

```
import requests
import json


false_count = 0
true_count = 0

qa_creatives = open("numbers.txt")
arraylist = []
for line in qa_creatives.readlines():
arraylist.extend(line.split())
qa_creatives.close()

arraylist = map(int, arraylist)



authorization_code = raw_input("please enter your authorization code: ")
creatives = arraylist
print "Creative Check script is now running, please wait."

for creative in creatives:
    url = "http://api.wiki123.com/v1.11/creative?id="+str(creative) 

    header = {"Authorization": authorization_code}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

    creative_check = json.loads(response.text)

final_creative_status = creative_check["response"]["creative"]["is_expired"]

#print str(creative) + " expired status: " + str(final_creative_status)

if final_creative_status == False:
    false_count += 1
else:
    true_count += 1

print "Creative Check Complete:"

print str(false_count) + " creatives are still valid"
print str(true_count) + " creatives have expired"
```

Here is a sample of the JSON data that is returned when making one of these GET requests:

```
{
'response': {
'count': 1,
'creative': {
  'prime_id': 1092343,
  'off_audit': None,
  'allow_audit': False,
  'allow_ssl_audit': False,
  'audit_feedback': None,
  'audit_status': 'no_audit',
  'backup_upload_status': None,
  'brand': {
    'category_id': 0,
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Unknown'
  }
  }}}
```

The odd thing is that this script works some of the time but other times, I get the following error: KeyError: 'creative'. I am puzzled by this because my requests should be returning the same thing each time and as such, the key should never change. Can anyone tell what might be going on here? Any recommendations on how I can debug this issue? If a certain "creative" is breaking the loop, what would be the best way to exclude it? Thanks.

UPDATED Code for my loop:

```
for creative in creatives:
    url = "http://api.wiki123.com/v1.11/creative?id="+str(creative) 

    header = {"Authorization": authorization_code}

    api_response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

    creative_check = json.loads(api_response.text)

    creative_status = creative_check.get("response", 
    {}).get("creative{}).get("is_expired", None)


if creative_status is None:
    pass

elif creative_status == True:

    true_count += 1 
else : 

    false_count += 1

print "Creative Check Complete: "

print str(false_count) + " creatives are still valid"
print str(true_count) + " creatives have expired"
```

Note: Now, I don't receive a key error back, but both of my counts for false_count and true_count are always 0 after my script has finished.

Comment: Apparently, some times the response does *not* return a dictionary with `creative` in it.

Comment: That's what I am figuring... if a particular "creative" GET request does not return data with the "creative" key in it, is there a good way to just spit those ones out? Or more specifically, put those in a separate list?

Comment: ... you could catch the `KeyError` and process it accordingly... no?

Comment: You can use :  `if "creative" in creative_check["response"] : ( ..Your code here.. ) else : Separate_list += [ creative_check["response"] ]`

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I am still new to Python: are you referring to using "try-except" to just weed out the error cases?

Comment: try-except is a good plan. You can print the stuff that's in error to see if there is something wrong with your assumptions.

Comment: @t.m.adam where would this if statement go? Would it go at the beginning or end of my For loop?

Comment: I assume you mean this for loop : `for creative in creatives:` .  It should go at the end after this line : `creative_check = json.loads(response.text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution :

```
for creative in creatives:
    url = "http://api.wiki123.com/v1.11/creative?id="+str(creative) 
    header = {"Authorization": authorization_code}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    creative_check = json.loads(response.text)

    creative_status = creative_check.get("response", {}).get("creative", {}).get("is_expired", None)
    if creative_status is None : 
        ## That means that the key 'is_expired' does not exist. ##
        ## You can handle this case here or just pass ## 
        pass
    elif creative_status : 
        # 'is_expired' is True 
        true_count += 1 
    else : 
        # 'is_expired' is False
        false_count += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I have added my updated code for my for loop in my original post. Now, I don't get any key error back, but both of my counts for "false_count" and "true_count" always come out to "0" as soon as my script is finished. I must be doing something wrong. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: 1 . It seems like you have a syntax error on line 10 : `get("creative{})`   should be `get("creative", {}) `  2 . If both false_count and true_count are 0 , it means that key 'is_expired' does not exist.    3 . Could you post some json data to verify that 'is_expired' exists and is either True or False ?

Comment: Also if you leave your if - else out of the for loop, it only applies to the last `creative_status`

Comment: That was it! It was an indentation problem on my part; after adding my if statement into the loop, the script works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
final_creative_status = creative_check["response"]["creative"]["is_expired"]
```

You want access in objects of json that doesn't exist. Put a try-except KeyError to catch the exception or put conditions like this:

```
if 'creative' in creative_check["response"].keys():
    if 'is_expired' in creative_check["response"]["creative"].keys():
        blablabla
```

I'm sure that in your json doesn't exist these objects.